# Loop iterates as many time as the number of characters in input

Tags: c, input, while-loop

I know my title is weird. I didn't know how to put it in words.

Basically, I have a loop that asks the user if they want to run the program again, "Would you like to run again (y/n).
If I enter one character It will loop one time. But if I enter 5 characters "hello" it will iterate 5 times.

ex.
Would you like to run again? (y/n)

q

Would you like to run again? (y/n)

Hello

Would you like to run again? (y/n)

Would you like to run again? (y/n)

Would you like to run again? (y/n)

Would you like to run again? (y/n)

Would you like to run again? (y/n)

This is my code:

```
 char a='y';
   while(a=='y' || a=='Y')
   {
   printf("Enter a p value: \n");
   scanf("%d",&p);
   printf("Enter a q value: \n");
   scanf(" %d",&q);
   printf("Enter a k value: \n");
    scanf(" %d",&k);

   for (i=p; i<q+1; i++)
   {
      Q=i;
      sum=0;
      count=0;
      while(Q>0)
      {
         count++;
         r = Q%10;
         sum = sum + pow(r,k);
         Q = Q/10;
      }

      if ( i == sum && i>1 && count==k )
      {
         printf("%d\n",i);

      }
      i++;
   }
   a='z';
   while(a !='y' && a !='Y' && a!='n' && a!='N' )
   {
      printf("Would you like to run again? (y/n) \n");
      scanf(" %c", &a);
   }
```

Comment: That's probably because you're asking for one character. Ask for the whole line and check it for allowed values. And read documentation for functions you are using in your code. And please use minimal examples when asking.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. I just changed scanf(" %c", &a); to scanf(" %s", &a);

Comment: That may work better, but it's still not correct as you're writing behind the address of `a`. If you don't want to care about buffers, `getline()` might be the choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, scanf takes it input arguments from a buffer. For every valid argument
(one that matches the format) scanf performs its job, but If it encounters an invalid
argument(that does not match the format) it leaves(skips) the argument in the buffer.

Now, in your code you are giving "Hello" as your input and using the format specifier "%c"
Thus scanf interprets your input as 'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', since you have used "%c" thus
it reads the input character by character and since all the five characters are valid
character input thus the output gets printed for all the five characters.